# How to avoid interepretation of string as command in CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have code which get PNPDeviceID of Videocard currently installed in system

```
FOR /F %i IN ('wmic path win32_VideoController get PNPdeviceid ^| findstr _') DO (SET fd="%i")
  
echo %fd%
  
C:\Users\user>echo %fd:~1,-1%
PCI\VEN_10DE
"DEV_0641" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
"SUBSYS_00000000" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
"1A8B4BFC" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
"0" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
"0008" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

When I try to display value of fd variable CMD interpret value of variable as chan of commands and try to execute it. Can I somehow avoid it? Because I need to store only part of this variable, but when i try to do it I recieve error message.
I understand that CMD see & sign and try to interpret it as command operator

Answer (score 2):

Use `echo "%fd%"` instead of `echo %fd%`. Doublequotes preserve cmd.exe from interpreting `&` as a command chaining character.